# AppleScripts run from Text Expander return System Events error

Tags: macos, applescript, textexpander

I recently set up a Mac as new instead of using Migration Assistant, or any other means of restoring my information, and am finding that all of the snippets I have set up in Text Expander that rely on AppleScript return the following error:

"Not authorized to send Apple events to (name of app)."

Here's what I've tried/checked so far:

- the scripts do work as expected when I run them out of Script Editor
- Text Expander is listed and checked in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility, as well as Full Disk Access.
- I tried running the following in Terminal:

```
tccutil reset AppleEvents; tccutil reset SystemPolicyAllFiles
```

- ran First Aid with Disk Utility

I know that on my previous Mac, Text Expander and other apps were listed in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Automation, but nothing is listed in there on the new computer. That being said, there's no way to manually add Text Expander to this section, and I'm not seeing a prompt to allow TE to control System Events.

Any help or suggestions you can offer would be appreciated!